# Remove the last two columns from a table in a txt file that's poorly formatted?

Tags: python, csv

To process data from Synchro into a readable format in excel, there are extra columns that should be dropped.

Raw Data from a txt file:

```
 Lane Group                   WBT   WBR NBL NBT NBR SBL SBT SBR Ø3  Ø7

 Lane Configurations          <1>    0   1   2>  0   1   2   1
```

Reading this txt file as a csv puts every line into a single string

My goal is to:
1.) read as a csv with correctly delimited rows/columns (using \t as a separator)

2.) Drop any columns and data after the 'SBR' column

Code I'm using:

```
AMtxt = pd.read_csv('AM.txt', sep='\t+', header = None, error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines = False, quoting=3, skiprows=1, engine='python')

AMtxt.drop(columns = AMtxt.columns[-2:], axis = 1, inplace = True)

AMtxt.to_csv('AM.csv')
```

When I try to use this, it removes the "Lane Group" row for some of the entries in the read_csv stage.

[What CSV should look like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPUq3.png)

[The CSV looks like for problematic entries (ones where there are data in the columns I'm removing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1yUr.png)

EDIT: SOLVED

```
AMtxt = pd.DataFrame(open('AM.txt','r').readlines())
AMtxt = AMtxt[0].str.split('\t', expand = True)

for column in AMtxt:
    AMtxt[column] = AMtxt[column].str.strip()

AMtxt.to_csv('AM.csv')
```

This method worked for me.

Comment: Never put `\n` into the set of possible column delimiters, it should only be a *row* delimiter. This is the cause of your scrambled rows. BTW does your initial file actually contains tabs (`\t` character)? It looks more like a Fixed Widths File than a CSV one...

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

I'm not certain if it uses actual tabs, \t works as a delimiter. Removing the \n causes me to lose more data when I get to the problematic entries - I lose every row instead of just ones that contain characters in the columns I want to remove

Comment: I think that the correct way is to process the file with [read_fwf](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html). But I cannot say more unless you provide the first lines of the file as they actually are...

Comment: Did @SergeBallesta's suggestion of using the "fixed width" function help? At least from the sample you provided, the columns are laid out with spaces, not tabs, but that just might be a copy-paste issue. Thanks! :)

Comment: Serge's suggestion might work, but it leads to a new problem where I can't figure out how to read the file with a delimiter using read_fwf. It can read the .txt file without errors, but it's all in one column

AMtxt = pd.read_fwf('AM.txt', header = None, delimiter = "\s+")

Comment: Rather than adding a solution to your question, you should add it as an answer. (Treat it as though you were answering someone else's question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution that worked for me:

```
AMtxt = pd.DataFrame(open('AM.txt','r').readlines())
AMtxt = AMtxt[0].str.split('\t', expand = True)

for column in AMtxt:
    AMtxt[column] = AMtxt[column].str.strip()

AMtxt.drop(columns = AMtxt.columns[-(len(AMtxt.columns) - 14):], axis = 1, inplace = True)
AMtxt.to_csv('AM.csv')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).